# /usr duplicate /

Tags: filesystems

I am learning linux file system from Centos and noticed that:

```
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z ~]# ls /
bin   dev  home  lib64       media  opt   root  sbin  sys  usr
boot  etc  lib   lost+found  mnt    proc  run   srv   tmp  var
```

and the /usr

```
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z ~]# ls /usr
bin  etc  games  include  lib  lib64  libexec  local  sbin  share  src  tmp
```

only one of them is a linked

```
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z ~]# ls -l /usr
total 120
dr-xr-xr-x.  2 root root 32768 Sep 18 22:44 bin
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  4096 Apr 11  2018 etc
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  4096 Apr 11  2018 games
drwxr-xr-x. 51 root root  4096 Jul  4 11:27 include
dr-xr-xr-x. 30 root root  4096 Apr 11  2018 lib
dr-xr-xr-x. 43 root root 36864 Aug 10 16:31 lib64
drwxr-xr-x. 24 root root  4096 Aug 10 13:53 libexec
drwxr-xr-x. 15 root root  4096 Aug 19 02:38 local
dr-xr-xr-x.  2 root root 12288 Sep  6 12:28 sbin
drwxr-xr-x. 96 root root  4096 Aug 10 16:33 share
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root  4096 Apr 11  2018 src
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    10 Jun 15 22:08 tmp -> ../var/tmp
```

Why they are identical to one another? Is it the rare case on Centos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a CentOS 7 system, `/bin`, `/lib`, `/lib64`, and `/sbin` are normally symbolic links to their corresponding directories in `/usr`.  You can see this by looking at the output of `ls -l /`.

The `/etc` and `/usr/etc` directories are distinctly separate.  In my experience, most programs check `/etc` for their configurations but likely can be configured to use `/usr/etc` if you really wanted to.